# Compilation error error C2039: 'clock_t' : is not a member of '`global namespace''

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors, ctime

I'm compiling in VS 2010 with boost 1_53.
I'm also using boost's threads.

during compilation i'm getting bunch of errors like this

> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ctime(18): error C2039: 'clock_t' : is not a member of '`global namespace''

all errors are about `ctime` and `c_time.hpp`.

i've searched around for the solution but without success.

can anyone, please, help?

here some part of code.

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_USE_DLL 

#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
```

Comment: If you are including `<ctime>` as `<time.h>`, you may be inadvertently including a completely different file depending on your includes path.

Comment: What is the first error you get? The rest might just be collateral damage.

Comment: Here is the first error:
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ctime(18): error C2039: 'clock_t' : is not a member of '`global namespace''

Comment: May be i need to add some preprocessor rules?

Comment: did you link boost? What's your make command?

Comment: @mikners Can you post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: @rubenvb I guess [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/88210/) could be the SSCCE. He is probably missing the link to boost as thread is not header only.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include boost::thread in your C++ project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174519/how-to-include-boostthread-in-your-c-project)

Comment: @Theolodis: I doubt that is relevant. Linker errors <-> compiler errors.

Comment: @rubenvb you are right... the first link contains the same problem though, with additional sample.

Comment: let me check the link.
additional include directories include boost.

Comment: also, i jsut want to mention, that some says that this error can be the result of namespace problem (not closing brackets)

Comment: i've installed boost with the installer downloaded from boost's site.

Comment: we need a short example which reproduces the problem. voting to close.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. I've learned a lot from the posted links. The solution was quite easy and somehow funny. Project has many dependencies from another projects. and additional directories include this : ../../Project;../../Project/SubFolder. 
after removing this all errors're gone.

Thanks again!

Comment: Not sure about VS2010, but if it lets you specify system include path separately to user include path - don't pollute system include path with junk from your projects; do all of that in the user include path.

Answer (score 20):

Something, somewhere in your codebase is including a different "time.h". I just discovered this migrating code from Linux to Windows - Because windows is case insensitive, a local "Time.h" (note the capital) was included as "time.h", causing the error that you see.

According to [someone's post](https://github.com/johmathe/Shotdetect/issues/1), FFMPEG can cause this problem via this precise mechanism.

Please look through your codebase and/or libraries for a "time.h" to see if this is happening.  Otherwise, an alternate option is to output the fully pre-processed source to see what is actually being compiled in the offending file.

Comment: This was exactly my issue - created my own header named "Time.h" and started experiencing the problem.