# Linker Errors using Boost Sourcecode

Tags: c++, boost, linker, boost-asio, linker-errors

I have a problem I can't get rid off.
I have a small private project where I want to use asio for network communication and boost threads. I don't wan`t install boost on my machine, so I integrated the sourcecode in my project. For that I created a global header including boost thread and asio, like this:

```
#include "boost/asio.hpp"
#include "boost/thread.hpp"
```

This way I can build static libs without problems, but shared libs or executables cause linker errors:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: bool __cdecl boost::thread::join_noexcept(void)" (?join_noexcept@thread@boost@@AEAA_NXZ) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl boost::thread::join(void)" (?join@thread@boost@@QEAAXXZ)
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::thread::id __cdecl boost::this_thread::get_id(void)" (?get_id@this_thread@boost@@YA?AVid@thread@2@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl boost::thread::join(void)" (?join@thread@boost@@QEAAXXZ)
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class boost::thread::id __cdecl boost::thread::get_id(void)const " (?get_id@thread@boost@@QEBA?AVid@12@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl boost::thread::join(void)" (?join@thread@boost@@QEAAXXZ)
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: bool __cdecl boost::thread::do_try_join_until_noexcept(unsigned __int64,bool &)" (?do_try_join_until_noexcept@thread@boost@@AEAA_N_KAEA_N@Z) referenced in function "private: bool __cdecl boost::thread::do_try_join_until(unsigned __int64)" (?do_try_join_until@thread@boost@@AEAA_N_K@Z)
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl boost::thread::interrupt(void)" (?interrupt@thread@boost@@QEAAXXZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl NetworkAdapter::~NetworkAdapter(void)" (??1NetworkAdapter@@QEAA@XZ)
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __cdecl boost::thread::joinable(void)const " (?joinable@thread@boost@@QEBA_NXZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl NetworkAdapter::~NetworkAdapter(void)" (??1NetworkAdapter@@QEAA@XZ)
```

The current configuration for using boost as source within project so far is:

```
#define BOOST_SYSTEM_SOURCE
#define BOOST_DATE_TIME_NO_LIB
#define BOOST_REGEX_NO_LIB
#define BOOST_THREAD_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_THREAD_DYN_DLL
#define BOOST_THREAD_BUILD_DLL
#define BOOST_CHRONO_HEADER_ONLY
#define BOOST_DATE_TIME_NO_LIB
```

Without this configuration linker asks for *.lib files for thread, chrono and so on.
According to boost homepage Thread and Asio are HeaderOnly, so why is the linker looking for lib, missing symbols - instead of using headers?
So what am I doing wrong?

Appreciating every hint :-)

Best regards,
Dan

Comment: What's your linker command line?

Comment: Where did you find the statement that boost thread is a header-only library? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2174542/2101267

Comment: Likewise, boost asio is header only, but depends in some cases on some libraries which are not: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/using.html#boost_asio.using.dependencies

Comment: I found it here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries - Point 3

Comment: What, the bit that says *"Boost libraries that must be built separately are:

    ...    `Boost.Thread` ..."*?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is caused by total failure to read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

From the [boost threading website](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread/build.html)

> Boost.Thread depends on some non header-only libraries.
>
> Boost.System: This dependency is mandatory and you will need to link
>   with the library. Boost.Chrono: This dependency is optional (see below
>   how to configure) and you will need to link with the library if you
>   use some of the time related interfaces. Boost.DateTime: This
>   dependency is mandatory, but even if Boost.DateTime is a non
>   header-only library Boost.Thread uses only parts that are header-only,
>   so in principle you should not need to link with the library.

So you're mistaken - it's not header only.